Nokia C110 crashing and not responding when plugged in for charging
My phone is a cheapy Nokia C110. When I plug it in for charging, it acts like the electricity in the walls is inputting way too much data for the phone to handle. It starts not responding, apps start shutting down and everything crashes to home screen.
I have plenty of space for processing, but every time I plug it in it, "downloads the universe," without downloading anything at all besides a charge to the battery. It really only does this when charging, not even when I'm actually downloading something.
It is heavily getting on my nerves and I already had one phone before it that acted stupid like this, it ended up a pile of scrap. This one I've never treated badly, but persists to get worse and worse. I am using the factory cable.
Can anybody help me fix this?

Have you checked traffic statistics which apps download the data? Because it could be caused by a legitimate app or by malware misusing your phone to generate money for someone by downloading (pretending to watch) ad videos.

Could you [edit] and expand on "starts downloading all the data"? How did you know it downloaded something? On the other hand, apps like Play Store only do updates while the device is on charge.

I edited the question hopefully they reopen it

It sounds like you are referring to "ghost touches" when charging. Generally this is a grounding problem which may be a physical phone defect. I would try with a different cable and charger to see if it resolves the issue. If not resolved I would also try different locations starting with a different outlet to different mains electricity location in case some odd interaction with how electricity is sent to your charger brick and phone. If still encountering "ghost touches" when charging, leaning toward bad USB-C connector on the phone.

Thanks for the edit that added the detail on the device behavior, question reopened. I edited the title to reflect the real issue because "downloading" is misleading and confusing to the readers.

As for troubleshooting, you might want to check the device log when the device is plugged in, and see if there are some particular errors and/or exceptions.
